# ANet A8 Pre-Heat PLA Issue

Tags: prusa-i3

When I go to Quick Settings/Pre-heat PLA, the computer dies the LCD screen goes blank the power supply makes weird noises and then about 2 minutes later, the LCD Screen goes back to the Printer Ready Main screen but there is no temperature change.

Comment: Does it happen when you issue other tasks, that can overload your power supply? For example, go to extruder menu and set extruder temperature to 200. Will it die? Home all axes from quick settings. Will it die? Set hotbed temperature from extruder menu to 80-100. Will it die? If the answer is yes for at least one question, you may have faulty power supply. You can check whether it continues to produce correct DC voltage when screen is blank if you have multimeter.

Comment: @kymber-nichols Change your power supply.

Comment: I agree with @FernandoBaltazar. This sounds like a power supply problem (or maybe a loose connection).

Comment: @kymber-nichols Yes, maybe a loose wire, try to touch the power wire to sense if not overheating, this indicates a faulty connection.

Comment: Unfortunately, up to now, no answers are given on your question! Have you found an answer yourself? If so, you may add your own solution and accept that after 48 hours. If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question so other people may help you find an answer. You can even decide to delete the question. We need to reduce the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered) to graduate from the Beta stage.